# Open mobile versions of some sites only?

Tags: website

Is it possible to only open mobile version of certain websites? (like [xda](http://forum.xda-developers.com/))

I have an [addon in firefox](http://chrispederick.com/work/user-agent-switcher/) that lets me do this but for all websites, whereas I only want this for 1 or 2 websites at most.

Comment: Why not use different user profiles in Firefox? Use the User Agent Switcher on the profile you want to use to access the mobile and the other don't use.

Answer (score 0):

Most mobile sites have their own URL. If you find the URL then you can just bookmark or write it down for use latter on your desktop. A lot of the time is just a m. in front of the normal URL.

Examples:

Microsoft http://m.microsoft.com CBC http://m.cbc.ca BBC http://m.bbc.co.uk/